# What does it mean: "The dance and the simple video are everything"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Here is the full phrase "But honestly the dance and the simple video are everything", and i took it from comments (on youtube) to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=au8QGTiPhEw

Could someone explain me the meaning? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special meaning. The youtube video is a music video. It is simply shot with a solo dancer.

The comment appears to be a follow-up or reply to another comment (but that other comment might be buried very deep in the comment thread). But according to the commenter, the dance and the simple video are the only important thing. It seems that the commenter likes the dancing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the explanation is close to what i am thinking. Also that comment  on youtube wasn't an answer to someone else's comment, as it seems to me. Though phrase vas very unusual for me and i suspected that it might have other meaning.

Comment: It was either a reply or, more likely a follow-up. The poster had previously written something else.  But that was 11 months ago and the first post has been submerged